# unable to load dbxmss.dll no Delphi XE4

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe4

Ao tentar conectar, em Delphi XE4, um TSQLConection com MSSQL, ele pede usuário e senha. 
Após ok, aparece:

> unable to load dbxmss.dll

Já busquei no computador e não há esta dll, nem na pasta bin do delphi. Também já busquei no site da Embarcadero.

Alguém sabe se estou fazendo algo errado ou se tenho mesmo que achar esta dll na rede?

Table criado com Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0 (SQL Server 2012).

Comment: Na versão do **XE3** eu tenho essa dll na pasta **bin** e na **bin64**. Pode ter sido um problema na instalação.

Comment: Eu já reinstalei o Delphi. Não aparece o tal dbxmss...
Tem o dbxmys.dll

Estranho.

Acho que vou ter que baixar, o problema é que não encontro na pagina da Embarcadeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri. O problema é que eu estou usando a versão Professional. Não dá suporte ao TSSQLConnection com MSSQL. 
ADOConnection é necessário para MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão essa Dll([Driver Dbxmss](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications)) está por padrão no diretório **Bin**(*`C:\Program...\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\<Versão>\bin`*) do Delphi.

Caso você não tenha o arquivo(*o que seria pouco provável*) você terá que baixa-lo e coloca-lo na pasta, ou realizar a *reinstalação/reparo*.